# How to fire a server-sent event only once?

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I am currently implementing server sent events onto my server/web page. I have implemented a simple php script that just echoes "1" and simple JavaScript that gets the message and displays it onto the screen. What I cant understand is why it repeatedly prints "1" onto the web page when it is not in a while look in the php script?

I have read multiple forums and articles and I cant seem to understand why it is doing this.

The php code is:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    $num = 1;

    echo "data: {$num} \r\n";
    @ob_flush();
    flush();
    usleep(500000);

?>
```

And the Javascript is:

```
var source = new EventSource("sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

I would expect the php file to be run once and the number "1" to be displayed on the screen however it seems to run every few seconds printing 1 on the screen repeatedly. Why is this?

Comment: it happens because the browser repeatedly re-connects to the event stream, causing the PHP to run again. Use the example from [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) where the PHP prints the current server time and you'll see it better, because it will print something different each time a call to the server is made. That page also discusses techniques for stopping the same event from being sent repeatedly, which I guess it kinda what you're asking about

Comment: So if the browser is reconnecting to the server every x seconds what makes this different from polling? I may have misunderstood the concept here xD

Comment: because if your stream doesn't end, then it doesn't need to re-connect. It opens a connection, and can receive any events sent during the lifetime of the connection. If the server closes the connection - which your script does, because it runs for a moment and then stops, the browser will assume there's a problem and then keep re-opening the connection unless you tell it not to. And since when the connection is re-opened, the PHP code starts again from the beginning, and doesn't track what it has sent previously, that's why you see the value repeated

Comment: P.S. you might want to consider using a PHP library such as this one (not recommended, just result of a random google search): https://github.com/hhxsv5/php-sse which will implement an SSE event stream on the server, keeping the connection alive, instead of closing it and opening it repeatedly.

Comment: Alternative here's a simple example showing how you can write your own event stream without using a library. It keeps the connection open with PHP by ensuring the script never ends (using an infinite loop i.e. `while(1)`): http://usefulangle.com/post/13/php-using-server-sent-events-for-logged-in-users

Answer (score 1):

Browser tries to reconnect after some time after connection closed. You can use `retry: X`  in your server response to set delay (in ms)

BTW. server-sent events aren't supported in Microsoft browsers (Edge 18 so far) - [CanIUse EventSource](https://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource)